# TagPrefix is not registered in this Web Form

Tags: asp.net

I've installed Entity Data Source 6.0 from Package Manager Console, then I Browsed to the installed DLL and added the new EntityDataSource to the toolbox then dragged and dropped it in my web form as follows:

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="EntityFrameworkProject._Default" %>

<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

  <div>
      <ef:EntityDataSource ID="EntityDataSource1" runat="server"></ef:EntityDataSource>
  </div>

</asp:Content>
```

In the "Design" View of my aspx page i'm getting the error:

> This control cannot be displayed because its TagPrefix is not
>   registered in this Web Form.

How can I register this TagPrefix? Also shouldn't Visual Studio have the prefix by default since it's has been created automatically?

Answer (score 2):

You need to register **ef** TagPrefix on the top of your aspx page like this

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="ef" Namespace="MyApp.Controls" Assembly="MyApp" %>
```

where **MyApp.Controls** is a namespace where your custom control is defined, and **MyApp** is a assembly of your custom control.

Comment: I guess the problem is that I know what namespace to add. I've added the dll to my toolbox, and I used MyProjectName.Controls as the namespace but that produced an error as there is no folder Controls in my project.

Answer (score 0):

With the `Microsoft.AspNet.EntityDataSource` package installed from NuGet (still version 6.0.0), the following is what should be added to the top of the page to register `<ef:EntityDataSource />`:

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="ef" Namespace="Microsoft.AspNet.EntityDataSource" Assembly="Microsoft.AspNet.EntityDataSource" %>
```